# Assigning value to an array or object inside a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, pass-by-reference

I am learning javascript and I read that in javascript array and objects are by default passed as a reference. So when I do this:-

```js
var a = [2, 3, 4]

function pushEl(a, num) {
  a.push(num)
}

pushEl(a, 5)

console.log(a)
```

The output is as expected which is

```
[2,3,4,5]
```

But what I am not able to understand is that when I assign value to an array or an object inside the function the original array/object is not changed.

```js
var a = [2, 1, 3]

function change(a) {
  a = [1, 2]
}

change(a)

console.log(a)
```

I expect the output to be `[1,2]` but the output is `[2,1,3]`.

If the array is passed by reference then the changes should have been reflected in the original array too.

Can anybody tell me what concept I'm missing here?

Comment: Take a look at the [scope of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) it might help you understand this behaviour

Comment: Globally defined array `a` and the function parameter `a` are two _different_ variables. When you call the `change` function, passing in the `a` array as a parameter, function parameter `a` holds a reference to the same globally defined array BUT when you re-assign the function parameter `a`, it now holds a reference to a different array (globally defined `a` variable is unaffected).

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding with the argument name... check it with this name: `function change(arg) { arg = [1, 2] }` actually you are editing the argument and not that `var a`